# failing to build swift ios application on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I haven't played around with iOS in a while, and now I'm remembering why I stay away. I'm trying to build my new application on my device, because it requires the microphone, and it is failing to do so. Below is the error message that I get:

```
Showing All Issues

PBXCp /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beethoven.framework /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/pitchee.app/Frameworks/Beethoven.framework
    cd /Users/*/workspace/pitchee
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -exclude Headers -exclude PrivateHeaders -exclude Modules -exclude *.tbd -bitcode-strip replace-with-marker -bitcode-strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beethoven.framework /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/pitchee.app/Frameworks

error: /Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beethoven.framework: No such file or directory
```

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting the **DerivedData** folder and then trying again.
2. Running **Product** > **Clean** and then trying again.
3. Deleting the certificate in the keychain, regenerating and then trying again.
4. Adding the Beethoven framework to the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** section.

[image: Adding the Beethoven framework]

Some things that might be notable:

1. The application is a SwiftUI application, targeting iOS 13.2. It's a possibly Swift 5.0 application.
2. The Pod (Beethoven) was installed using **Cocoapods**
3. The Pod (Beethoven) targets iOS 8.0
4. The Pod (Beethoven) had to have its source code converted to Swift 4.0
5. Using XCode **Version 11.4** (11E146)

It is possible to build my application, as is?

Comment: have you tried navigating to a folder  
/Users/aemengo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pitchee-bklwfakpvazvegapgfgacyfhyrod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Beethoven.framework

Comment: Before you criticize Xcode, maybe you need to look into how to use/update third party libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by:

**Paying for an Apple Developer Membership**